# Installing cocos2d 2.0 XCode templates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to instal the cocos2d 2.0 XCode 4 templates but I keep getting errors when running the install script. I've tried to manually copy the templates but when I try to compile my project, it gives me a bunch of errors. Can anyone help?

Here are the errors that the install script throws at me:

http://pastebin.com/ZdmAxwef

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Also have this problem.. unable to find a solution. This script can't be run with sudo either.

Comment: What I did to get it to work was I removed the part in the install script which doesn't allow you to run as root. Then I ran the script as root and everything copied successfully. Built and ran a project and no errors :)

Answer (score 4):

You probably install the cocos2d 1.x templates using root. Since installing as root isn't supported anymore, you first have to chown them back to your user.

Answer (score 3):

There are three things you can try:

First, make sure you are running install-templates.sh as sudo

```
cd *location of cocos2d-2.0 folder*
sudo ./install-templates.sh -u -f
where -f forces the installation
```

Second, you may need to change the install-templates.sh script to install to a different location (try both your user and directly to the Machintosh HD)

Third, (which is what i often have done in the past) is copy the folders over to the correct directory (or at least make the directories the mkdir are failing on and try again)

Comment: It keeps telling me that 'root' is no longer supported. I also keep getting rsync errors.

Comment: Replace after sudo in the second line with: ./install-templates.sh -f

Comment: `sudo` doesn't work, even with the -f at the end. I just took `sudo` off the front and it installed with no errors. Now I have to find out how I can import it into an Xcode project!

Comment: Same here, did it with just "./install-templates.sh -u -f" .

Answer (score 3):

I followed these exact instructions

> cd /src/cocos2d-iphone-2.0/
>
> ./install-templates.sh -f

which i found here http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:migrate_to_v2.0

side note- on my mac hard drive "Macintosh HD" i created a folder src and copied the cocos2d-iphone-2.0 folder in it. and im running mountain lion and Xcode 4.4
this worked perfectly for me.

hope this helps

Comment: I've got that bit working, but how do I use it in Xcode? I tried `#import "cocos2d.h"` but it doesn't seem to be able to find it...

Answer (score 0):

This is many years ago

- The **Solution** is simple now, you know longer need to do any of this just.

install the latest version of Cocos2D from

[cocos2d-swift.org](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org)

it will install everything automatically including the templates. just start a new Xcode project and it just be there in the template options